# Element with :first-letter can't be selected

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In **Chrome** (Version 55.0.2883.87 m) (win 8.1) text in element with :first-letter can't be selected (in full) with mouse selection.

Does this have a workaround without javascript?

```css
div:first-letter{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div>
unselectable
</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to select the 'n' as well here.

Comment: its not working for me. Btw nice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a known bug in Chrome for a while now, dating back since 2009.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17528

A 'hacky fix' can be applied by using a HTML comment before the text, you still can't select the U (but you can select the n). But copy-pasting the selection will actually give you all the content in the div.

```css
div:first-letter{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div>
<!-- -->unselectable
</div>
```